# Using Monotouch with Google .NET APIs

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, libraries, google-api

I am using Mike Bluestein's article, http://mikebluestein.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/using-monotouch-with-the-net-library-for-the-google-data-api/, to build an application that communicates with the google APIs.

When I try to add references to my project, the imported projects say "incompatible target framework: v2.0".  I can change version to 1.1, 3.0, or 3.5 with the same results.

If I add the .dll to the monotouch project I get a compilation error - monotouch failed with no output 134.

Any suggestions?

http://macpapa.com/macpapa.com/public-images/SM.png

http://macpapa.com/macpapa.com/public-images/PM.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think regular .NET dlls will work on an iphone - Notice that the article is using source code and project references, not assembly references. Did you follow the instructions on changing the build targets of the google projects?

Comment: I changed the target of the builds, but instead of a 'Mono for iPhone' option, I am given 'Mono / .NET 1.0', 'Mono / .NET 2.0', 'Mono / .NET 3.0' or 'Mono / .NET 3.5'.

Comment: Have you set the ProjectTypeGuid in the csproj files you are working with?

Comment: I see the is very important stuff in the update.  I will let you know how is goes.  thanks

Comment: Setting the ProjectTypeGuid was the key.